# Problem with InDesign TOC

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I have created paragraph styles and TOC styles but when I go to load the TOC style it displays 2 numbers- the correct one and the current page number (roman numeral since it is front matter) The update TOC is also grayed out. Can anybody help me with this frustrating problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an additional section break which is giving you the roman index? You may want to put up some screen grabs of your Paragraph Style panels and TOC panel